# SSRS field color expression for updated values

Tags: reporting-services, service, reporting, msbi

[image]

In the above image, there are 2 rows for a single ID.  I want them to be coloured for the updated field values as follows:

- for id `100` Email was updated so this should be coloured as a different colour.
- for `101` City was updated
- for `102` City *and* State both are updated

I want to colour the updated fields as shown in the image above, in an SSRS report.

Comment: You table appears to be in excel?  Have you got your SQL script or your  SSRS report, to show us what you have done so far?

Comment: actually my data is in SQL , and the report is automated in SSRS, just for an explanation I have used excel.

Comment: In that case, "Have you got your SQL script or your SSRS report, to show us what you have done so far?"

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS you can use the [Previous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx) function to compare a value to the one in the previous row. For example you could use an expression like this for the background color:

```
=IIf(Fields!ID.Value = Previous(Fields!ID.Value) AND Fields!City.Value <> Previous(Fields!City.Value), "Red", "White")
```

Comment: TanQ so much for the expression ,

Comment: @Anil glad to help. Please mark as answered if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the dataset query, you can try something like below:

In same row you will get the previous values. Then, it will be much easier to use conditional statements. Below is for SQL Server (T-SQL), you can try similar if not using SQL Server.

```
Select t1.*
, t2.email as prev_email
, t2.city as prev_city
from table t1
left join table t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.rownum = t2.rownum - 1
```

And, set the textbox fill expression with like for `Email` column:

```
=iif(isnothing(Fields!prev_email.Value) or Fields!email.Value = Fields!prev_email.Value,"White","Red")
```